# Get second camera from camera.main property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have two camera with "MainCamera" tag in a scene.
using this line of code

> camera.main.transform.name

I am getting camera name but the problem is, it is only **showing one camera**  name (which is fine) No matter what is depth or order of both main cameras in hierarchy.

How to get **only** second camera instead the one it is showing!
I only want to use camera.main property and **nothing else option**.

Answer (score 2):

Camera is nothing but a [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) with a [Camera](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) component attached. So it is very simple to get all instances of the camera:

```
var cameras = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera));
foreach (Camera camera in cameras)
    Debug.Log (camera.name);
```

[image]

Comment: i think using camera.main only brings the camera that was tagged mainCamera first , mb he shuld tag it different , am i correct david?

Comment: How to get only second camera instead the one it is showing! I only want to use camera.main property and nothing else option.

Comment: i know that i can get all but i only want to use camera.main option .

Comment: You cannot. Basically you are making two potatoes, but you just want to say one is potato, and the other is tomato. You can do this only if you pretend that you are ignorant of it.

Comment: @LumbusterTick, I am with you, but it seems the OP is reluctant to do so.

Comment: you can't say "i want somethign done" but i only want to use this "not appropriate property"

Comment: haha @David i feel u mon , I wanted to confirm because i knew the way he asked the question its the only way he is thinking.

Mr.Faizan please try this : 1 remove mainCamera tag from object named Main Camera and voila problem solved , touche to twisted ways .Leaving negative point to question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to access the camera inside a rendering method (OnPreRender, OnPostRender, ...), you can access the camera currently rendering via [Camera.current](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-current.html).
Other than that, there is no way to get a "second main" camera. Camera.main, will always return the **first** enabled main camera. You have to go with David's solution.